# injecting javascript code from front end

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I am currently working on an application which has its all javascript and css code unminified on production but zipped using gzip. One of the problem is that end users can easily read and steal the code which is not a big problem in this scenario. Second thing that worries me is that is it secure? I mean can someone from the front end read the code and modify or inject some code from the front end? If yes then please tell me how this is possible? I need this answer to convince my boss that we need to minify the code on production.

Comment: And what is your concern here? Why is it a problem if people modify the CSS or Javascript on their computer? If you think that's a security issue, you have the wrong understanding of security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code minification is not done to obfuscate code, but to decrease the amount of bytes which will be send to the users.

Your minified or plain JavaScript lands on the user's machine in the end so user can change it anyway.

Do not treat minification as a security mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

normally you should not have sensitive information in the css and and front end javascript so that should not be an issue. minified code is simply taking a lot of the characters out so the final javascript "library" is smaller. In return it's faster to load which adds up to better performance apps. You need to tell you boss you want to minify the code so the app works faster and is more "portable" not because it helps security. Security is another issue more likely tied to your database and front end form handling etc.

Answer (score 1):

Gzip compression provides no protection at all for people viewing the source and allows the output from your server to be compresses before being sent to the client.  You can read more about Gzip compress specifically in the Apache manual [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).

The JS and CSS is also not secure in the sense that anyone can read and modify it on their local machine.  Minification is not designed to keep your code secure, it's designed to reduce the size of it.